# Handling user action when clicking on push notifications

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification

I have two type of push notifications in my app Type A and Type B and according to each type I want to navigate the user to different view controls. right now the app show only the homeVC if user clicked on the 
notification and can I pass value from the notifications object to the
view controls.?

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
   userInfo["Type"] as? String == "TypeA" {
        showNotificationA()
    } else {
        showNotificationB()
    }
    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
}


 func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
       // How to identify which notification the user clicked to navigate to the right view?
        if UIApplication.shared.applicationState == .inactive {    
        }
        completionHandler()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the handling of push notifications consists more or less of the following steps:

1. Enabling Push notifications in the capabilities section of project settings
2. Requesting the access to use remote and local notifications, and delegating incoming notifications to your notification observer entity (class, struct)

This is done in the AppDelegate class, in a similar manner to:

```
 UNUserNotificationCenter
         .current()
         .requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .badge]) { (granted, error) in
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = MyCustomDelegateEntity
         }
```

3. Implementing the `func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void)` in your delegate, which receives incoming notifications
4. Notifications can be distinguished by an identifier, which is located in the UNNotificationResponse entity. Based on the id, you can decide how to react accordingly.

In your particular case, you should instantiate a desired view controller from the NotificationDelegate in a similar manner to

```
let rootVC = MyViewController.instantiateFrom(storyboard: "StoryboardName")
let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: rootVC)

(UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate)?.window?.rootViewController = navigationController
```

The ViewController.instantiateFrom(storyboard:) content looks something like:

```
return UIStoryboard(name: storyboard, bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: String(describing: self)) as! MyViewController
```

Answer (score -1):

You can redirect all your notification to one controller and in this basview controller check which notification type its came from and navigate accordingly.

You can pass data from notification payload and handle accordingly

Comment: how can I redirect the notification and pass payload?